# c# savefilediaglog saving text of specific length

Tags: c#, streamwriter, savefiledialog

my code is-

```
Stream myStream;
saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Ticket files (*.tkt)|*.tkt";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save text Files";

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
   if (myStream != null)
   {
       StreamWriter wText = new StreamWriter(myStream);
       string st = gettxt();
       wText.Write(st);
       //wText.WriteLine("sdfsderfsdsf");
       myStream.Close();
    }
}
```

whenever i uncomment Writeline and comment write(st) notthing is written..
and the string should be of specific length then only data is saved in the tkt file..
and last problem is that if text is too large then part of the text is only written..
please help me

Comment: flush and close the streamwriter before you close the stream

Comment: It look slike the problem is in `gettxt()`. What is the value of `st` at the point of being written?

Comment: do you need to write the whole gettxt()-String in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are very few ways to explain the problem, other than there's a problem with the app that reads the file.  Beware that you are writing a .txt file, it might not necessarily be compatible with a .tkt file format.  Whatever that looks like.  For one, the file will contain a BOM, 3 bytes at the start of the file that says it is a utf-8 formatted text file.

One thing you could try to diagnose the problem better:

```
   using (var wText = new StreamWriter(myStream, Encoding.Default)) {
       string st = gettxt();
       wText.Write(st);
       //wText.WriteLine("sdfsderfsdsf");
   }
```

The Encoding argument specifies that the characters should be written in the default code page and without a BOM.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
   tw.WriteLine(gettxt());
   tw.Close();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Ticket files (*.tkt)|*.tkt";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save text Files";

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (Stream myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
    {
        using (StreamWriter wText = new StreamWriter(myStream))
        {
            wText.WriteLine(gettext());
        }
    }
}
```